# Validate textfield on action

Tags: ios, uilabel

I'm not sure how to ask this question which has made it hard to search the forum. I'm not sure what to ask...

But I want to check a labels text to see if it contains a valid date after the action button is selected

```
- (IBAction)addIncomeButton:(id)sender {

if (self.selectDateLabel.text == 0){
    self.displayLabel.text = @"Please Select a Date";
}else{

"The rest for my insert statement"
```

Is this even close?

UPDATE:

Ok, I now have a better understanding of what I was trying to accomplish.

Heres what we ended up with;

```
- (IBAction)addIncomeButton:(id)sender {

if ([self.selectDateLabel.text  isEqual: @"No Date Selected"])
{
    self.displayLabel.text = @"Please Select a Date";

    }else{
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**length**

```
if (self.selectDateLabel.text.length == 0){
    self.displayLabel.text = @"Please Select a Date";
}else{

}
```